# Where should I ask a given question, how and why is it vague what I am asking in said question?

Tags: discussion, support, site-scope, asking-questions, down-votes

[What is the academic( research, teaching, learning) use of advanced mathematics in Economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/36479/what-is-the-academic-research-teaching-learning-use-of-advanced-mathematics)

Where should I ask the question cited above, how and why is it vague and unclear what I am asking?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one reason why the [original, unedited] question is vague.  One of the most useful mathematical topics for economics is multivariable calculus, eg when finding the optimum of a function containing separate variables for the quantities of each of a number of goods.  Does that count as an advanced topic? Perhaps not.  On the other hand, it's probably a bit beyond the introductory calculus some students learn at high school.

Comment: I listed what I consider advanced mathematics. Calculus; multivariate or not, is not advanced it is not Real Analysis. Multivariate calculus is the very first thing we learn in University( in an undergraduate Economics course). We learn Lagrange Multipliers and Optimization with Definite Positive and Definite Negative Jacobian Matrices in Mathematics of Economists I and Estimation in Statistics for Economists I how to find the BLUE. I don't understand the use of what I consider advanced( mainly functional calculus and ergodic theory).